# AWS IoT Shadow - How to handle or reject invalid "desired" states?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

AWS IoT Shadow has support for dealing with invalid states. From my understanding of the AWS documentation, when a message is published to `/update` and it is considered invalid (e.g. because it is invalid json), an error message is published to `/update/rejected` per specification here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-shadow-error-messages.html
This is clear, but it only concerns generic state update failures.

**Question:**

What if an AWS IoT shadow state update is valid from the point of view of the AWS IoT Shadow service, but it is *not* a valid desired state from the point of view of the device?

**For example**, say a device supports `"state": {"desired": {"color": "red"}}` and `"state": {"desired": {"color": "green"}}`.
What is then a good way or best-practice to deal with a request for `"state": {"desired": {"color": "black"}}` if the device does not support black? 
Can this be communicated over any of the default shadow topics?

Note: I found a similar (unanswered) question here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=300362

Comment: Have you found anything useful regarding to problem?

Comment: @sardok: not really. For other reasons, we have moved away from using the Shadow feature of IoT Core, And in that approach, we implement a simple request  - acknowledge response mechanism, with a specific mqtt topic for the acknowledgment response. So, depending on the content of the request, a positive ack (e.g. 202) or nack (e.g. 400) is sent, with some additional info (request id, some nack details). It might make sense to do something similar along side the IoT shadow topics, on separate topic(s)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem and found this post on the AWS forum:

https://repost.aws/questions/QUx_YtxvdmTFODhuuNd4D_Yw/how-to-deal-with-shadow-updates-initated-by-device-not-and-server

Basically, the client can clear the "desired" section of the device shadow document to show that it has rejected the changes. This will prevent any more "delta" messages for that particular change. You can clear the device shadow "desired" section by posting a message to **/update** with **null**, as follows:

**Clear entire desired section:**

```
{
    "state" : {
        "desired" : null
    }
}
```

**Clear an individual field:**

```
{
    "state" : {
        "desired" : {
            "MyField" : null
        }
    }
}
```

However, this will not inform the other end (cloud, mobile app, etc) that the "desired" state they requested was invalid.

To do that, you might be able to post your own message to **/update/rejected**, although I haven't tried this.